# How would we answer the following question about piecewise limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

[image]

It seems like the limits I think should be calculated are in fact wrong. That seems to be my problem.

Any help on what the correct limits I should be calculating are and why the ones I have typed above are wrong? I even tried interchanging the two but they are still wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: The question is about $f'(0)$, not $f(0)$.

Comment: I see. So should I calculate the derivative of each part of the function and instead but those into the respective blank spaces? If not, then what should be my approach? Thank you!

Comment: You should attend to the **definition** of derivative.

Comment: $f'(0)$ is the rate of change of function at that point(0) , not the limiting value of the function at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the definition of derivative, to compute $f'(0)$ we need to compute the left hand limit

> $\lim_{x \to 0} 2-14x$

which is

> 2

and the right hand limit

> $\lim_{x \to 0} 14x+2$

which is

> 2

We conclude that $f'(0)$ is

> 2

Comment: Since $f(x) = 2x - 7x^2$ when $x < 0$, the left hand limit of the derivative should be $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} (2 - 14x)$.  Since $f(x) = 7x^2 + 2x$ when $x \geq 0$, the right hand limit of the derivative should be $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} (14x + 2)$.  You reversed the left and right hand sides.

Comment: Corrected......